# How to Change Background Menu active with get url page on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need my menu active with get url page on browser.

example: 
if my url page http:myweb.com/mypage.html or http:myweb.com/mypage.html#p1 
will active my menu1 with background red

and if my url page http:myweb.com/mypage.html#p2 
will active my menu2 with background green.

```css
#p1:target { background: red;}
#p2:target{ background: green;}
#p3:target{ background: blue;}
#p4:target{ background: yellow;}
#p5:target{ background: coral;}
#p6:target{ background: skyblue;}
```

```html
<!--- My menu --->

<div id="menu">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tbl-menu"/>
    <label for="tbl-menu"><img src="drop.png" height="40px"  width="40px "alt=""></label>
        <nav class="nav">
         <ul class="tombol">
         <li class="tombolmenu"><a class="t1" href="#p1">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a class="t2" href="#p2">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a class="t3" href="#p3">Menu3</a></li>
            <li><a class="t4" href="#p4">Menu4</a></li>
            <li><a class="t5" href="#p5">Menu5</a></li>
            <li><a class="t6" href="#p6">Menu6</a></li>
          </ul>
         </nav>    
      </div>

<!--- My page target --->

<div id="p1">  Page1 </div>
<div id="p2">  Page2 </div>
<div id="p3">  Page3 </div>
<div id="p4">  Page4 </div>
<div id="p5">  Page5 </div>
<div id="p6">  Page6 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with :target selector. In your code example `#p1:target { background: red;}` will add background: red on `<div id="p1">  Page1 </div>`

One solution with your given code would be to use javascript (jquery in my example) to highlight the selected menu item.

```js
var $navElement = $("nav li a");

$navElement.click(function () {
  $("[class^='t']").not(this).removeClass('active');
  //[class^='t'] selects class starting with the letter t
  $(this).addClass('active');
  //e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.t1.active { background-color: red;}
.t2.active{ background: green;}
.t3.active{ background: blue;}
.t4.active{ background: yellow;}
.t5.active{ background: coral;}
.t6.active{ background: skyblue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="tombol">
    <li class="tombolmenu"><a class="t1" href="#p1">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a class="t2" href="#p2">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a class="t3" href="#p3">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><a class="t4" href="#p4">Menu4</a></li>
    <li><a class="t5" href="#p5">Menu5</a></li>
    <li><a class="t6" href="#p6">Menu6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i need like this website with active menu

Comment: @OjanMri You mean u need to stick that menu to top and and scroll the page?

Answer (score 0):

One more solution using pure **Javascript**:

```js
// at work environment replace next line with this: var addr = window.location.href;
var addr = "google.com/index.html#p2" // this line is as example of script work.
var arr = addr.split("#"); // split URL to 2 parts divided by #
var ref = arr[1]; // select part of URL which comes after #
var t = document.querySelectorAll('[href="#'+ref+'"]'); // find all elements <a> with related href, result is array
t[0].parentNode.className = ref; // assign className to parent node of first element of found <a> array
```

```css
.p1 { background: red;}
.p2 { background: green;}
.p3 { background: blue;}
.p4 { background: yellow;}
.p5 { background: coral;}
.p6 { background: skyblue;}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tbl-menu"/>
    <label for="tbl-menu"><img src="drop.png" height="40px"  width="40px" alt=""></label>
        <nav class="nav">
         <ul class="tombol">
         <li class="tombolmenu">
             <a class="t1" href="#p1">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a class="t2" href="#p2">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a class="t3" href="#p3">Menu3</a></li>
            <li><a class="t4" href="#p4">Menu4</a></li>
            <li><a class="t5" href="#p5">Menu5</a></li>
            <li><a class="t6" href="#p6">Menu6</a></li>
          </ul>
         </nav>    
      </div>

<!-- My page target -->

<div id="p1">  Page1 </div>
<div id="p2">  Page2 </div>
<div id="p3">  Page3 </div>
<div id="p4">  Page4 </div>
<div id="p5">  Page5 </div>
<div id="p6">  Page6 </div>
```